# How do I deal with the error "No instance for (Control.Monad.IO.Class.MonadIO [])"?

Tags: haskell, random, monads, do-notation

Good evening everybody! This is a question concerning Haskell. I want to get `x` random elements from a list by using a function.

The problem I get is that when I try to use random numbers, with `randomRIO`. I get the error message:

```
No instance for (Control.Monad.IO.Class.MonadIO [])
        arising from a use of `randomRIO'
```

This error message suddenly goes away when i use print or return. But I dont want to use `print`, and `return` messes up the output to a nested list  `[[a]]` instead of `[a]`.

Does any of you have a tip on what I can do to extract `x` random elements from the list, in the form of a list?

The type would be something like this. `xRanElems :: [a] -> Int -> [a]`
where the second `Int` is an accumulator but I got that covered.

```
xRanElems xs n = do
  r <- randomRIO (0, n)
  xRanElems2 xs n r
```

where `n` is just `length xs - 1`

```
xRanElems2 xs n r = (xs !! r) : (xRanElems (xsWithOutSelectedElem xs r) (n-1))
```

Thankful for any input!

Comment: `return $ xRanElems2 xs n r`?

Comment: Thank you, Yes I tried that but it caused problems because xRanElems2 is recursive I believe. It tells me that it expects [a] but actual is [[a]]

Comment: And I think return does something with the the list that messes it up in some way.

Comment: As usual: if you're doing `IO`, you have to admit it. Write `xRanElems :: [a] -> Int -> IO [a]` and your error messages will be much more informative. (Similarly for `xRandElems2`, but changing one will give you errors about the other to remind you.)

Comment: Oh okay, I will try that, so a random generated number is of IO class? Thanks

Comment: It works kind of, but then reaches the second problem i mentioned. Namely that it complains that it expexts [a] and not [[a]]. I dont know how it even made it into [[a]] but I think it has something do do with return

Comment: @SnusSwag: “a random generated number is of IO class?” Close, but not exactly. You can use an `IO` action to produce a random number, for example, if you want an action that produces a new random `Int` from 1 to 6 each time it’s executed, you could define `rollD6 :: IO Int; rollD6 = randomRIO (1, 6)`. You can combine `IO` actions using `do`/`Functor`/`Applicative`/`Monad` functions, and assign them to `main` to be executed, but an `IO X` isn’t an `X`, and it doesn’t even *contain* an `X`, it just represents some code that could *produce* an `X` value.

Comment: Mm okay I get it now, I have seen something similar during a recorded lecture but it didn't stick. Thanks for your comment!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following typechecks:

```
import System.Random

xRanElems  :: [a] -> Int -> IO [a]
xRanElems xs n = do
  -- randomRIO :: Random t 
  --           => (t, t) -> IO    t
  r <- randomRIO  (0, n)  -- r :: Int
  xRanElems2  xs      n      r    

xRanElems2 :: [a] -> Int -> Int -> IO [a]
xRanElems2 xs n r = 
   let (a,b:c) = splitAt r xs 
   in 
     fmap (b :)                --     [a] ->    [a]
          (xRanElems           --  IO [a] -> IO [a]
               (a++c) (n-1))
```

Trying to run it, e.g. with `xRanElems [1..3] 2`, reveals that it loops forever.

This is because you need to provide the base case in `xRanElems` to stop the recursion, e.g. `return`ing `[]` when `n <= 0`.

The above code also contains an off-by-1 error which you're invited to fix.

Comment: splitAt was new for me. fmap solved the issue! That blew my mind. I got the other problems taken care of. Thank you, have a good dinner!